# Property 'submitted' does not exist on type 'UpdateEmployeeComponent'

Tags: angular

Hello I am trying to build a simple crud application using angular and spring boot

I am getting one error while compiling my code. Since I am new at this, I cant seem to resolve it. 
The error message is below:

```
ERROR in src/app/update-employee/update-employee.component.html:2:16 - error TS2339: Property 'submitted' does not exist on type 'UpdateEmployeeComponent'.

2 <div [hidden]="submitted" style="width: 400px;">
                 ~~~~~~~~~

  src/app/update-employee/update-employee.component.ts:8:16
    8   templateUrl: './update-employee.component.html',
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    Error occurs in the template of component UpdateEmployeeComponent.
```

Here is my update-employee.component.ts file:

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
 import { Employee } from '../employee';
 import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
 import { EmployeeService } from '../employee.service';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-update-employee',
 templateUrl: './update-employee.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./update-employee.component.css']
 })
 export class UpdateEmployeeComponent implements OnInit {

 id: number;
 employee: Employee;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,private router: Router,
  private employeeService: EmployeeService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
 this.employee = new Employee();

 this.id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];

 this.employeeService.getEmployee(this.id)
  .subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data)
    this.employee = data;
  }, error => console.log(error));
 }

 updateEmployee() {
 this.employeeService.updateEmployee(this.id, this.employee)
  .subscribe(data => console.log(data), error => console.log(error));
 this.employee = new Employee();
 this.gotoList();
  }

 onSubmit() {
 this.updateEmployee();    
 }

   gotoList() {
 this.router.navigate(['/employees']);
  }
 }
```

And here is my update-employee.component.html file:

```
  <h3>Update Employee</h3>
  <div [hidden]="submitted" style="width: 400px;">
  <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div class="form-group">
  <label for="name">First Name</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" required [(ngModel)]=
  "employee.firstName" name="firstName">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
  <label for="name">Last Name</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" required [(ngModel)]="employee.lastName" 
  name="lastName">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
  <label for="name">First Name</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" id="emailId" required [(ngModel)]="employee.emailId" 
  name="emailId">
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
  </form>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is correct, I don't see a `submitted` member variable in the controller. The the following

Controller

```js
export class UpdateEmployeeComponent implements OnInit {
  submitted = false;

  onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;
    ...
  }
}
```

Moreover, the navigation should be inside the subscription to avoid jumping to a new page before the list is updated.

```js
export class UpdateEmployeeComponent implements OnInit {
  id: number;
  employee: Employee;
  submitted = false;

  constructor(
    private route: ActivatedRoute, 
    private router: Router,
    private employeeService: EmployeeService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.employee = new Employee();
    this.id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    this.employeeService.getEmployee(this.id).subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log(data)
        this.employee = data;
      }, 
      error => console.log(error)
    );
  }

  updateEmployee() {
    this.employeeService.updateEmployee(this.id, this.employee).subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log(data)
        this.employee = new Employee();      // <-- I presume this is a placeholder
        this.gotoList();                     // <-- Navigate here
      }, 
      error => console.log(error)
    );
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.submitted = true;
    this.updateEmployee();
  }

  gotoList() {
    this.router.navigate(['/employees']);
  }
}
```

Comment: I added this.submitted = true; in my method but I am still getting the same error.  ERROR in src/app/update-employee/update-employee.component.ts:40:10 - error TS2339: Property 'submitted' does not exist on type 'UpdateEmployeeComponent'.
    
    40     this.submitted = true;   Please help.

Comment: Did you define the `submitted = false;` at the start of the class?

Answer (score 1):

Declare a variable submitted at the start of the class and assign false to it, on Submit change it to true.

Ts:

```
export class UpdateEmployeeComponent implements OnInit {
  submitted: boolean = false;
   onSubmit() {
 this.updateEmployee();    
 this.submitted = true
 }
}
```

Comment: As said by @Michael D please move this.gotoList(); inside subscription, otherwise before subscription is resolved, the page will move to the defined route